# How to make a React component have more than 2 or 3 states, etc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still wrapping my head around React. I'm making a file upload component. I want the component to display three different states as the upload occurs. I'd like it to initially display the select file input field, then when the user submits that form I want it to display some sort of "uploading ..." message, and finally when the upload has completed I want it to say something like "finished!"

Right now, I've got it displaying the input field, and then the "uploading" message when the form is submitted. I'm just looking at the components state and depending on the state, I return one or the other item in `render`.

Should I just follow this same pattern up to as many render states as needed? This could end up with a huge if-else block, and that'd be fine?

Here's my component for context ...

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

import React from 'react';
import connectToStores from 'flummox/connect';


/**
 * Repositories
 */

import * as Replays from '../repository/ReplayRepository';


/**
 * Components
 */

import ReplayUploadForm from '../components/ReplayUploadForm';


/**
 * Component definition
 */

class ReplayUploadFormContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor() {

    super();

    // pre-binding
    this._handleUploadAttempt = this._handleUploadAttempt.bind(this);

    // initial state
    this.state = {
      signed: null
    };

  }

  render () {
    if (this.state.signed) {
      return (
        <h2>Uploading ...</h2>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <ReplayUploadForm onUploadAttempt={this._handleUploadAttempt} />
      );
    }
  }

  _handleUploadAttempt (file) {

    // request signed upload request
    Replays.sign(file).then(response => {

      // update component state
      this.setState({
        signed: response
      });

      // start file upload
      Replays.upload(file, response).then(response => {

        console.log(response);

      });

    });

  }

}


/**
 * Module exports
 */

export default ReplayUploadFormContainer;
```

Comment: Yes that could be fine. You're building a little "state" machine, so you might `switch` and use a `case` statement, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes but you can do more about the `if ... else ...` thing

you can write an object like the following

```
var uploadStatusComponent = {
    'uploading': <div>uploading</div>,
    'finished': <div>finished</div>,
    'ready': <div><input /></div>
};
```

and then using the state to get the right component like

```
var theCurrentComponent = uploadStatusComponent[this.state.signed];
```

then you can get rid of the `if else` or `switch case`

Comment: Note that in 0.14+ these can and should (performance) be placed outside of the component, but in 0.13 it must be inside render.